# JVM based text editor?

Tags: text-editors

Are there any JVM based editors out there that have:

1. Good text-editing capabilities: keyboard shortcuts, commands etc (like VIM or MACS)
2. Good plugin system using jvm based languages (so that one can extend it with, say, Scala)
3. Plain UI (not like word or jedit)

Can't seem to find any...

Comment: So... a console (text-only) text editor, written in pure JAVA? O.o

Comment: I didn't say console (see Gvim or Windows based Emacs). Also - how can someone downvote a question??? It makes no sense... At least have the cojones to say why.

Comment: What do you mean by "Plain UI"?

Comment: I guess one that is not cluttered with rows upon rows of buttons, windows and dialog boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps [JEdit](http://www.jedit.org/)

- Written in Java, so it runs on Mac OS X, OS/2, Unix, VMS and Windows.
- Built-in macro language; extensible plugin architecture. Dozens of macros and plugins available.
- Plugins can be downloaded and installed from within jEdit using the "plugin manager" feature.
- Auto indent, and syntax highlighting for more than 130 languages.
- Supports a large number of character encodings including UTF8 and Unicode.
- Folding for selectively hiding regions of text.
- Word wrap.
- Highly configurable and customizable.
- Every other feature, both basic and advanced, you would expect to find in a text editor. See the - Features page for a full list.

Comment: "Plain UI (not like word or jedit)" -> Yeaaah... that's the only candidate, and he killed it in his own question.

Comment: Perhaps I should reconsider jEdit - it seems to have a vim-emulation plugin... @Shiki stop raging, go eat a melon.

Comment: You may want to look up the word "rage" in a dictionary. Also, I just wanted to point out, that your question just includes the only potential candidate, and also, kills it (i.e. point 3). Nevermind, gotta fetch a melon.

Comment: @Shiki hope you can someday forgive my past me for that stupid question.